# How can I input and destroy the other gameObject on Trigger

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I want to destroy a GameObject when it hits the trigger but with an input. No errors, but its not working in unity

```
using UnityEngine;

public class DestroyTile : MonoBehaviour
{
    private void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
    {
        if (other.CompareTag("Tile"))
        {
            if(Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space))
            {
                Destroy(other.gameObject);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

what should I do to make this work??

Answer (score 1):

Very unlikely that you manage to hit the key in exactly the **same frame** the collision happens ;)

As a quick fix rather use [`OnTriggerStay`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.OnTriggerStay.html)

> OnTriggerStay is called once per physics update for every Collider other that is touching the trigger.

```
public class DestroyTile : MonoBehaviour
{
    // Called once every FixedUpdate for each trigger you are touching
    private void OnTriggerStay(Collider other)
    {
        if (other.CompareTag("Tile"))
        {
            if(Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space))
            {
                Destroy(other.gameObject);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

---

With above way there is only one last issue: `OnTriggerStay` is not actually called every **frame** but rather every `FixedUpdate` so you might miss a key press if it happened in a frame where `FixedUpdate` isn't called. Therefore in general getting User input within `FixedUpdate` (or other physics based continuous methods) is unreliable and should always be done in `Update`.

So instead you could/should do something like e.g.

```
public class DestroyTile : MonoBehaviour
{
    private readonly HashSet<GameObject> _currentlyTouching = new HashSet<GameObject>();

    private void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
    {
        if (!other.CompareTag("Tile") return;

        // For some reason we still have the other object stored
        if(_currentlyTouching .Contains(other.gameObject)) return;
       
        // Store the other object
        _currentlyTouching.Add(other.gameObject);
    }
    
    private void OnTriggerExit(Collider other)
    {
        // We don't have this other object stored
        if(!_currentlyTouching.Contains(other.gameObject) return;
        
        // remove this other object
        _currentlyTouching.Remove(other.gameObject);
    }
    
    private void Update()
    {
        // Are we touching anything?
        // This check is cheaper than Input.GetKeyDown
        if(_currentlyTouching.Count <= 0) return;

        if(!Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space)) return;
        
        // destroy (all) the touched object(s)
        foreach(var obj in _currentlyTouching)
        {
            Destroy(obj);
        }

        // Don't forget to also clear the HashSet in that case
        _currentlyTouching.Clear();
    }
}
```

This way you have the User Input separated in `Update` (every frame) and only track the entering and exiting colliders via the Physcis based system.